# different MacBook battery models since 2008?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I am wondering if Apple changed the form factor of their MacBook (Pro) batteries since Early 2008?
I was planning to replace my broken MacBook Mid 2010 Unibody with a used MacBook Pro from early 2008. However, the battery life of my MacBook 2010 was ~4-6 hours still, where the battery of the MacBook Pro I am interested in only lasts ~2 hours.

So, it would be nice if I could simply swap the batteries. Unfortunately I didn't find that many infos on the battery shape and compatibility.

What I read here was that the battery of the 2008 Pro has 60 Watt, and the battery of the 2010 MacBook model has 63.5 Watt. I am not sure in how far these 60 Watt might be just an approximation and if not, if it could cause problems.

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.6-15-early-2008-penryn-specs.html

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-mid-2010-specs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the batteries are completely different between the 2008 and 2010 models.

No, you can not swap them between the two.

Comment: Too bad, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Welcome.  I know sometimes you one just needs a clear answer on this things.

Comment: I would add that the unibody batteries are something you should have a trained technician swap since there are delicate parts and improper handling of fully charged lithium ion batteries can be an immediate safety hazard and improper reassembly could become a hazard if loose parts are left inside the case.

Comment: Thanks, but now the swap won't happen anyway.